# Git says local branch is behind remote branch, but it's not

Tags: git, git-push

Scenario:

1. I make a new branch
2. hack on it
3. commit it
4. push it
5. hack on it some more
6. commit again
7. try to push again

Git responds:

> Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
>   its remote counterpart. etc.

I'm the only one hacking on this branch - no one else is touching it.  The remote branch is actually *behind* the local branch.  I shouldn't have to pull at all.

(And if I do pull, Git reports conflicts between the two, and forces me to merge the branch into itself)

Why is this (likely) happening?  And how can I diagnose/fix it?

To be clear, I'm not branching anywhere, and *no one else* is working on it:

```
Remote: Commit A -------- Commit B  

Local:  Commit A -------- Commit B -------- Commit C
```

C is a straight continuation of B, no branching involved.  But git thinks C is a branch of A:

```
Remote: Commit A -------- Commit B  

                  ------- Commit C  
                /  
Local:  Commit A -------- Commit B
```

It's not; it's a straight continuation of B.

Comment: The output of `git remote -v` and `git show remote origin` (assuming origin is the remote you are having trouble with) may be helpful

Answer (score 201, accepted):

You probably did some history rewriting? Your local branch diverged from the one on the server. Run this command to get a better understanding of what happened:

```
gitk HEAD @{u}
```

I would strongly recommend you try to understand where this error is coming from. To fix it, simply run:

```
git push -f
```

**The `-f` makes this a “forced push” and *overwrites* the branch on the server. That is very dangerous when you are working in team.** But
since you are on your own and sure that your local state is correct
this should be fine. You risk losing commit history if that is not the case.

Comment: That was it.  At step 2, I did an "Amend Last Commit", then pushed, then hacked some more, then tried to push again.  I misunderstood the way Amend works.  Thanks!

Comment: This seems really useful - but could someone explain the 'HEAD @{u}' syntax?

Comment: Both the `HEAD` and the `@{u}` refer to commits. They tell gitk, which branches to display. `HEAD` refers to the currently checked out branch, `@{u}` is short for `HEAD@{u}`, which represents the upstream branch of the currently checked out branch. So for eg. `master`, that is usually `origin/master`.

Comment: Had the same scenario - had to do a rescan and merge conflicts. Using `gitk` helped a lot!

Comment: Happens to me if I make many simple commits locally (not ammend), and try to push. I know nobody else is changing things on github. Gitk really showed like the remote was different than the local, despite it is expected, it should show the local as a newer version than the remote and not the remote as a fork (looked like that, I dont know much gitk to tell)

Answer (score 6):

The solution is very simple and worked for me.

Try this :

```
git pull --rebase <url>
```

then

```
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me when I was trying to push the develop branch (I am using git flow). Someone had push updates to master. to fix it I did:

```
git co master
git pull
```

Which fetched those changes. Then,

```
git co develop
git pull
```

Which didn't do anything. I think the develop branch already pushed despite the error message. Everything is up to date now and no errors.

Answer (score 0):

To diagnose it, follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12651399/1422630).

But to fix it, knowing you are the only one changing it, do:
1 - backup your project (I did only the files on git, ./src folder)
2 - `git pull`
3 - restore you backup over the many "messed" files (with merge indicators)

I tried `git pull -s recursive -X ours` but didnt work the way I wanted, it could be an option tho, but backup first!!!

Make sure the differences/changes (at git gui) are none. This is my case, there is nothing to merge at all, but github keeps saying I should merge...