# Unable to push to remote branch

Tags: git

I do the below in my master branch:

```
git fetch --all

git reset --hard origin/master
```

Then i create a new branch and switch to the new branch using:

```
git checkout -b new_branch
```

I edit and add some files in the `new_branch`. Then i finally `commit`.However, when i push the changes, i get the below message:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

I have already seen these threads,but still the error persists:

[Cannot push to GitHub - keeps saying need merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298291/cannot-push-to-github-keeps-saying-need-merge)

[Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25237959/updates-were-rejected-because-the-tip-of-your-current-branch-is-behind-hint-its)

What else am i missing, i fail to understand?
Just to add, i have also deleted `my_branch`, again updated the `master` with the latest `remote`, recreated the new branch, still i encounter the same error, please suggest where i might be going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can force your push with the -f switch. The -f switch forces the push, and will overwrite the branch on the server. Use with caution when working in a team.

```
git push -f origin new_branch
```

Comment: there are chances, i might bypass the remote repo commits, will that not be a problem ?

Comment: yes, have you performed a pull first? git pull origin master

Comment: yes, i did a git pull quite a few times, but why does it still say, tip of my current branch is behind remote counterpart, why at all does this message appears ?

Comment: Have a look at the history to see what has happened: gitk HEAD @{u}

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650261/git-says-local-branch-is-behind-remote-branch-but-its-not

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
git pull
```

If this branch is new, then you can set the upstream with:

```
git push -u origin new_branch
```