# Git push not working, no error

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to push my commits to Bitbucket using the command

```
git push origin master
```

Nothing happens. I am represented with a command prompt, and no error message. When I browse the source online, my code has not been uploaded.

```
git remote show
```

returns "origin"

```
git push --verbose
```

Does not show any additional information.

I have pushed many times using this method, but it suddenly just stopped working.

I am using `2.6.1.windows.1` on Windows 10

UPDATE:
It appears to a problem with Git itself. I can't push, pull, or clone any repository on both GitHub or Bitbucket. It seems that any git command that connects to a remote isn't working.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling git. I tried installing both, 2.6.1 and 2.7.0 (2.7 didn't even install properly on Windows 10 Build 14251). I can interact with the repo without an issue on other computers.

Comment: Try `git branch -avv` to see where your local and remote branch pointers are at. Then use `git log <sha1>` or `git log --graph <sha1>` to figure out where these commits are positioned in the history.

Comment: My local branch is ahead by 1 commit. I am the only person working on this project, and there is only one branch.

Comment: I'm having similar issues with bitbucket git as well... Weird, i've pushed 30+ times today. Suddenly it doesn't respond anymore. Straaange.....

Comment: Git push stopped working for me, so I re-installed it, and then all git commands stopped working. I was using git in Cygwin, and the problem was that my Cygwin installation was out-of-date. Everything was fixed after I updated Cygwin.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same error, push/pull/clone would execute with no errors, no feedback, but nothing happended. What helped was to install latest GIT and when option "*Choosing HTTPS transport backend*" option came up I have selected "*Use the native Winbdows Secure Channel library*" and it all worked again ... Hope this help someone.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped. Else I don't have any way to guess this.

Comment: This worked. I had the exact same problem, also with 2.14.1 setup. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This worked for me too. I Installed the newest git version and it worked.

Comment: Worked for me for GitHub. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you are in a [detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309) mode ([`git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD` is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11958481/6309)), which would explain why a git push fails silently.

If you do have a legitimate branch checked out, then [the other test is to make a new clone, import your changes and try to push from that new clone to see if the issue persists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14435169/6309).

```
git clone /url/repo
git remote add work ../previousrepo
git fetch work
git reset --hard work/master
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: I am honestly not sure what any of that means, but I typed it in. 

I got back `master`

Comment: @Dave and `git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD`? By the way, I have added links to explain what it means.

Comment: @Dave Also, what version of git are you using, on which OS?

Comment: Thanks for the links. In any case, the command is returning `master`. I am using `2.6.1.windows.1` on Windows 10

Comment: @Dave Strange: you are on master, which is ahead by 1 commit... Looks like https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/7397/git-push-not-working

Comment: @Dave Can you try it in a new clone (as I suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/14435169/6309)

Comment: It does look that issue that you linked to. I will try it in a new clone first thing tomorrow morning and report back. Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my git pushes and git commits not showing up on Bitbucket.

Problem specifics: My Bitbucket updates had been working fine. I stopped working on the project for a day or two in my environment (Cloud9 in this case). When I resumed, my Cloud9 terminal showed that I was in the correct branch when I typed the command:

```
git status
```

However, no changes appeared in my Bitbucket branch.

My solution:

- Within Bitbucket, click on "Branches" either on the side panel or within the main window.
- You will see your branches. Click on the branch you're working in your environment, and that you want to push into.
- Once inside the desired branch, there should be a button in the top right (unless they change the template) called "Checkout." Click on that.
- Bitbucket provides the following message: Check out this branch on your local machine to begin working on it. It also provides the following code to type or paste into your terminal:

  ```
  git fetch && git checkout static-pages
  ```
- Run that command in your terminal.
- This should reset the connection.
- Try your git push. It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

This is a open issue in Bitbucket, as @ahmed says. The updated open issue is [here](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/12314/users-getting-packet-corrupted-from-ssh).

They recommend power cycling your modem. Alternatively, you can use a different wifi source, which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in Bitbucket:

https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/7567/git-push-remote-end-hung-up

Edit: i solved the issue by using SSH Tunneling:

```
% proxychains git push -u origin master  
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
|DNS-request| bitbucket.org 
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:1080-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<><>-OK
|DNS-response| bitbucket.org is 104.192.143.3
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:1080-<><>-104.192.143.3:22-<><>-OK
Counting objects: 3388, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1089/1089), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3388/3388), 2.79 MiB | 85.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3388 (delta 2312), reused 3343 (delta 2281)
To git@bitbucket.org:username/web-app.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```

Comment: I can't clone a repo from GitHub either, so I don't think this applies to me. I've updating my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue and resolved  it by renaming my branch without symbol `'`.

I think remote repos doesn't support branch names with `'` symbol.

Comment: I'm inferring your local branch name previously contained the `'` character, which you assume to be the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This was my case:

I was using the WSL terminal within VS Code and somehow I tried to `git push` in several ways but it just didn't work. It worked with `git pull`, `git clone`, etc but not with `git push`.

What worked for me is just to switch from using VS Code to using the WSL terminal directly and it immediately worked.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was an issue with Bitbucket and the new app passwords.

Create a password here.

https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/

Update or install git (Not sure if this was even need but adding here anyway)

```
brew install git
```

Now open up a new terminal window and try and push it should ask you for a password type in the one you created.

And you should be good to go.