# how to push an existing local branch to remote at gitHub?

Tags: eclipse, git, version-control, github

I'm using sourceTree.

How can I push an existing local project (branch) to

a remote Gitbug repository I won?

I try and get this error:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags --set-upstream memPic master:master 
Pushing to https://github.com/elad2109/memPic.git
To https://github.com/elad2109/memPic.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/elad2109/memPic.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
Completed with errors, see above
```

but anyway I'm not sure what are the required steps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298291/cannot-push-to-github-keeps-saying-need-merge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a github problem but a git problem. You can't make a non-fast-forward push without merging/rebasing. Please check the corresponding parts of the documentation.

[This](http://marklodato.github.io/visual-git-guide/index-en.html) site is a great help for understanding the problem!

So you basically either have to `git pull` or `git pull --rebase`.

Answer (score 0):

This is failing because the tip of your branch is behind its remote.  This might happen if there was a fetch without a rebase.

There are two ways to fix.  To keep the remote changes add `git rebase`, before your command.  To discard the other changes (not recommended) add a `-f` to your push command.