# Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g

Tags: github, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes.

I was trying to push local octopress blog to remote branch.
But its saying above error.

another is: Do i have to manage or push the local changes to **source or origin branch**.?

When i do username.github.io ,i shall see my remote version of the local blog.(i used rake deploy command)
But i dont see the updated blog at my username.github.io.I have doubt on branch for origin and source.

Comment: I'm adding this because the question mentions **Octopress**. In my case `rake deploy` was not working because I had modified the Github repository from the website (in my case adding a CNAME file). 

What fixed the site publication was doing `git pull` **inside the `_deploy/` folder**. After that `rake deploy` was able to publish my changes.

Answer (score 83):

You need to merge the remote branch into your current branch by running `git pull`.

If your local branch is already up-to-date, you may also need to run `git pull --rebase`.

A quick google search also turned up this same question asked by another SO user: [Cannot push to GitHub - keeps saying need merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298291/cannot-push-to-github-keeps-saying-need-merge). More details there.

Comment: The important thing is to ensure you're merging the remote branch into your current branch when you do `git pull`.

Comment: `git pull` says `Already-up-to-date` but when i do `git push origin my-current-local-branch` it still gives me the same error mentioned on the title of this thread

Comment: @Awesome_girl did you fix this? I have the exact same issue, keeps saying my branch is already up-to-date but when I try and git push it says I'm behind

Comment: git pull --rebase
This goes over the same issue. 
https://youtu.be/IhkvMPE9Jxs?t=10m36s

Comment: thanks your comment worked for me, But when I run git pull --rebase an error There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.... so when i ran git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master then git pull --rebase worked perfectlly... stupid read me file caused me all that

Comment: I followed the steps mention by @HusseinNasser as both git pull and git pull --rebase was showing already upto date. And it worked

Comment: I had this exact same problem. I solved it using the SourceTree App and just did a 'push' to the remote server.

Comment: My issue was I had a branch on the server with the same name as the local branch. I just needed to delete the remote branch and my push worked.