# Avoid recursive merge in Git

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, fast-forward

I have a git repository with two branches: `master` and `live`. I work on `master`. Once I deem my changes ready for production, I merge them into `live`, which is checked out in the production system. I work on the project alone.

With this setup, `live` always used to simply be a few commits behind `master`. So when I did a `git merge master` on `live`, the merge would be performed via `fast-forward`.

As of recently, doing `git merge master` while on `live` results in a merge performed by the `recursive` strategy. I don't know if the reason for this is that I once accidentally committed a change first on `live`, and only afterwards merged it onto `master`.

`git diff master live` yields no output, ie. the two branches have the same file contents.

What can I do to get my git repository into a "clean" state so it again uses the `fast-forward` strategy by default?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly asking for fast-forward merges with `git merge --ff-only master`?

Comment: Instead of using `git diff`, try `git cherry -v master live` (and `live master`). This will tell you what commits are the latter branch that aren't on the former. If you made a commit on `live` and then later `merged` it to `master`, it could have ended up with a different commit hash (even though your file contents are the same)... so maybe things started to skew from there?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. @dg99: `git merge --ff-only master` gives `fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.`. @hinerm: `git cherry -v master live` (and `live master`) both give no result. So strange!

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem was caused because:

1. I accidentally committed something (let's call it `A`) on `live` instead of `master`.
2. I then committed something else (`B` say) on `master`.
3. I realised I made the mistake 1. and merged `live` onto `master`.
4. I still needed to merge `B` onto `live`, so I merged `master` onto `live`.

I think this created a "crossing" of commit paths that makes it impossible for `git merge` to fast-forward.

The solution was to first ensure that the two branches really did have the same contents:

```
git diff master..live
git cherry -v master live
git cherry -v live master
```

all yielded no result. Then I changed `live` to point at exactly the same commit as master:

```
git branch -f live ae5e70... # Hash of the commit pointed to by master
git push --force origin live:live
```

Now I can fast-forward again. Note that [this can be dangerous and should probably not be done when the repository is shared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25729329/4571464).