# Can't push changes to git

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase

I have to branches, master and bryan.

I have pulled everything to master and rebased it to bryan.

When I make a change in my bryan branch, and try to push it, I get this error message:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
```

Why do I get this message all the time? I have merged the changes with git rebase.

Comment: What was the commands you used for the pull and the rebase?

Comment: @VonC: I do the following steps: 1. git checkout master 2. git pull 3. git checkout bryan 4. git rebase master

Comment: Can you post the relevant output of `log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all`?

Comment: @NilsWerner: I get this output: No command 'log' found,

Comment: `git log ...` obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git pull`
3. `git checkout bryan`
4. `git rebase master`

Any `git pull` includes a `git fetch`, which will update all remote tracking branches (`origin/master` and `origin/brya`n)

You have update `master` with `origin/master`, but not `bryan` with `origin/bryan`:
Adding a `git pull` between step 3 and 4 would help there.

But, by rebasing `bryan` on top of `master`, you changed its local history.
You would need to force the push (and be careful if other devs were developing from the same `bryan` branch).

Comment: So in the future, I should do a pull between 3 and 4? And to push my changes I have now, I should do a force push?

Comment: @user500468 pull as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/10298391/6309, and force push only for the bryan branch, because a rebase change its history.