# Issue with Git push

Tags: git

As you can see from the picture the last 4 commits from me haven't been pushed because another person made a commit before me and I did not pull. Now it says that I am 4 ahead and 1 behind. When I try to push it says:

```
    To git@XX.XX.XX.XX:compudoc.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@XX.XX.XX.XX:compudoc.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. If you did not intend to push that branch, you may want to
hint: specify branches to push or set the 'push.default' configuration variable
hint: to 'simple', 'current' or 'upstream' to push only the current branch.
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298291/cannot-push-to-github-keeps-saying-need-merge

Comment: ^^^ I would not follow the highest rated answer there!!!

Comment: First pull the all latest changes. `git pull origin master`. It might lead to some conflicts resolve them and push.

Comment: @PriyanshuShekhar I did that but the same  error appears when I push

Comment: Give your question a descriptive name. Say **what** the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

So you can't push before pull.
type `git pull`, when `git push` or `git push origin master`
Good luck.

Comment: When I try that it says: `You are not currently on a branch. Please specify which
branch you want to merge with. See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>`

Comment: You are on deatched head. If you want to save your changes, type `git checkout -b tmpbranch`, when commit your changes `git commit -am "msg"`, when `checkout master` and `merge tmpbranch`

Comment: If you don't want keep your changes, you can `git stash`, when `checkout master` or you can `git add .`, `git reset --hard`, and when `git checkout master`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull `master`, rebase it and then you can push.

`git fetch origin`

`git rebase origin/master`

`git push origin master`

Run those 3 in order and you should be good to go. Rebasing will show up any merge conflicts if you have them.