# How can revert a remote git repository?

Tags: git, github

I clone my own repository from `github` to local machine, do a small change, then `git push` it. The `git log` likes this:

```
3: xxxxx  
2: yyyyy 
1: zzzzz
```

I suddenly find there is an error in `commit 3`, so in local repository, I do `git reset 2` first, modify the file again, then `git commit` it. So the `git log` changes to this:

```
4: ttttt
2: yyyyy
1: zzzzz
```

This time when I `git push origin`, the `git` complains:

```
To https://github.com/NanXiao/torch.git
! [rejected]        patch-1 -> patch-1 (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/NanXiao/torch.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So how can I revert the remote repository? Make the remote repository's `git log` like this:

```
4: ttttt
2: yyyyy
1: zzzzz
```

Comment: If you found an error in commit 3, then the correct command is `git revert 3`. If you did a `git revert 2`, then that undoes the good change `yyyyy` and leaves intact the bad change `xxxxx`.

Comment: I am very sorry, it is `git reset 2`.

Comment: No, it isn't.  Doing `git reset` will not leave you with a new commit.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: After `git reset 2`, I modify and create a new `commit`.

Comment: Clean up your original question so it is unambiguous and then message me once you have done so.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Very sorry for confusing you and Raymond. Update it, please refer, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot push to github - keeps saying need merge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298291/cannot-push-to-github-keeps-saying-need-merge)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recap what you actually did to your branch, you started out with this:

```
3: xxxxx
2: yyyyy
1: zzzzz
```

You decided there was a problem with commit `3` so you *nuked* it using `git reset --hard HEAD~1`, leaving you with this:

```
2: yyyyy
1: zzzzz
```

Then, you made a new commit on top of this branch:

```
4: ttttt
2: yyyyy
1: zzzzz
```

The `non-fast-forward` error you saw makes sense since Git has no way of simply adding commit `4` on top of the remote branch which either still ends in commit `3` *or* ends in another commit which someone else made on top of commit `3`.

That being said, if you want to force your current branch to the repository, you can do so via:

```
git push origin your_branch --force
```

Take heed when doing a force push because it can cause problems for anyone else who is currently working with your branch.

Comment: I am very sorry, it is `git reset 2`.

Comment: `git push origin your_branch --force` is my need, thanks!

Comment: @NanXiao Yes...this is my feeling from reading your updated question.  I will update my answer as well now.

Comment: Slightly safer is `--force-with-lease` which will reject the push if somebody pushed to the branch while you weren't looking. This helps prevent accidentally reverting somebody else's work.