# Do I have to create files on github before pushing via Git?

Tags: git, github

I am having an issue with pushing to my repository using Git on Github.  [The error is attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDwRz.jpg)

What I want to know now is that do I have to create the files as a placeholder on Github before pushing my codes to it. I am really confused.

Thanks.

Comment: Please paste the error message as a text in your question, not an image.

Comment: Please read the error message.

Comment: And please read the error message. Your local branch is behind the remote branch. Pull the changes before push your local changes.

Comment: @MarounMaroun there error message is much that is why I decided to use the image. Have you been able to load the image?

Comment: @CodeCaster I am really new to Git. Please any help?

Comment: @Philj0 Ok, thanks I will try that.

Comment: Sorry, but we all were new to Git once, that's no excuse for not reading. The error message tells you everything you need to know.

Comment: The error message is in text. Please be courteous and post the text of error messages instead of screenshots. Also if you read the error message while posting it you will see it suggest doing a `git pull` first to bring down changes on github you don't have locally before doing a push. Have you tried following that suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot push to GitHub - keeps saying need merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298291/cannot-push-to-github-keeps-saying-need-merge)

Answer (score 0):

Your error message clearly states that you have pull the changes locally to your machine by using the command `git pull` then you can push

PS. if you pull the changes and the push right away you will be pushing the same thing that you pull so you will be prompt with a error.

You need to commit what you have done before merging.

So commit and then pull.

```
git add foo.js
git commit foo.js -m "commit"
git pull
git push
```

Answer (score -1):

No, you don't need to create the files as a placeholder on Github before pushing your code to it.

Comment: Thanks, but what is the solution? I am not getting it right, have you seen the image?

Comment: I did, but your question was so precise I felt I had to give a precise answer

Comment: You answered the title, not the question.

Comment: It seems to me that the only question is: *What I want to know now is that do I have to create the files as a placeholder on Github before pushing my codes to it*

Comment: so make a proper question, and you will get a proper answer