# Why am I not able to set the git upstream of the current branch to another repository?

Tags: git

Output of `git push --set-upstream staging master`:

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:exampleOrgAbcxyz/infrastracture-staging.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I have a `staging` remote. And I'd like to push the `staging` branch of my current repo to the `staging` remote on it's `master` branch.

---

```
git remote -v
composer    git@bitbucket.org:exampleOrgAbcxyz/infrastructure.git (fetch)
composer    git@bitbucket.org:exampleOrgAbcxyz/infrastructure.git (push)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:exampleOrgAbcxyz/infrastructure.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:exampleOrgAbcxyz/infrastructure.git (push)
staging git@bitbucket.org:exampleOrgAbcxyz/infrastracture-staging.git (fetch)
staging git@bitbucket.org:exampleOrgAbcxyz/infrastracture-staging.git (push)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot push to GitHub - keeps saying need merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298291/cannot-push-to-github-keeps-saying-need-merge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git push staging master` will attempt to push the **`master`** branch from your local repo to the `master` branch in the `staging` repo. In this case it fails because your local `master` is behind the remote one.

To push your `staging` to remote `master`, you want `git push staging staging:master`.  Or `git checkout staging`, followed by your original command.

Comment: Thanks! I've been using that command all along anyway. I didn't realize it's the same command without the `--set-upstream`! The final command that worked was `git push --set-upstream staging staging:master`.

Comment: Right, `--set-upstream` is irrelevant in this issue actually. It sets up the upstream for the branch. You only ever need to specify `--set-upstream` once per branch.