# Understanding git commit with amend option

Tags: git, commit, git-commit, git-extensions, git-amend

let's say i have a file 'A'
i have modified the file and pushed it to the repository by the following commands

```
git add A
git commit -m "changed A"
git push
```

later after i have realised that i need  changes in file 'B' so i have modified it and ran following commands

```
    git add B
    git commit --amend -m "changed AandB"
    git push
```

but i get error..

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://xxx@github.com/xx/xx'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

what should i do to overcome that error

Comment: Remember, you don't need to push constantly. Only when you wish to share the commits with others.

Comment: What do you try to avoid by amending commit A? Is there a reason **not to** just commit B on top of A?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot push to GitHub - keeps saying need merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298291/cannot-push-to-github-keeps-saying-need-merge)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Amend** actually changes the git history. You need to do force (-f) push to update the remote.

N.B: force push will replace the remote's history with the local's history so, it's **dangerous**.

```
$ git push -f
```

Comment: what are all available flags..? 
one is -f , do we have any other flags which i can use at the very point of moment

Comment: `$ git push --force`. `-f` is the shortcut of `--force`