# Git push weird behavior

Tags: git, github, push, pull

I am working on a branch called sofian/issue_533. I simply want to add the changes to the branch on git and somehow I can't.

Here is a picture of what git is showing ...

Thanks for the help !

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot push to GitHub - keeps saying need merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298291/cannot-push-to-github-keeps-saying-need-merge)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pull from the remote source first, your local branch is not up-to-date. Look in the logs, git tries to hint at it.

And also, beware of `git push` without any parameters, depending on your config, it might try to push all your local branches to their remote counterparts, which can be very unwanted. `git push origin HEAD` is safer.

Comment: Did not need to pull anything as Git said, the problem was the git push command. Thanks !