# Git rejects push after reordering commits

Tags: git, github, push

I had been working on 2 features of a project, on the `master` branch.

Let's call them `Feature #1` and `Feature #2`.

The `Feature #2` commit is the most recent.

None of the commits was pushed to remote until it was time to push the `Feature #2` commit.

But the attempt to push the latest commit with

```
git push origin ab34567dff766d0b5bd8698faffcfacf937e06d4:master
```

would push the previous commit too, *unless* I reordered them.

So I reordered the commits (using `git rebase -i HEAD~2`).

I have git pulled and `git status` gives the message:

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
```

`git push origin ab34567dff766d0b5bd8698faffcfacf937e06d4:master` is rejected:

```
Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
```

What shall I do?
What is the source of this problem?

Comment: It seems *incredibly* suspicious that you have a branch that looks like a SHA.  Show us the output of `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all`.

Comment: @Makoto I have followed **[this](http://blog.dennisrobinson.name/push-only-one-commit-with-git/)** tiutorial.

Comment: @Makoko, that's not a branch. That's the id of a revision he wants to hold on a remote branch.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/1sB3a0T.png

Comment: @RazvanZamfir are you sure that your local master branch is correct

Comment: @SamuelJMathew Yes, I am sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot push to GitHub - keeps saying need merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298291/cannot-push-to-github-keeps-saying-need-merge)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding from your comment that local master is perfect and you want to make the remote to be in same as local then you can try.

```
git push --force
```