# Difference between specifying refspec with git push --tags or not

Tags: git, git-push

I stumbled upon this rather obscure problem pushing tags to a remote using the two commands `git push --tags` and `git push --tags origin master`. They are not behaving the same in the following situation:

## Initial situation

I am trying to push a newly created tag (`git tag test`) to a remote repo that is one commit ahead because somebody else pushed a commit to it and I did not pull the latest changes. As graphic:

```
Remote [master] (one commit ahead):
A ----- B ----- C ---- D
Local  [master] (one commit behind):
A ----- B ----- C 
            (tag:test)
```

### Problem

`git push --tags` is working as expected:

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://remote.gitrepo.com/path/to/project
 * [new tag]         test14 -> test14
```

`git push --tags origin master` gets rejected and errors:

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://remote.gitrepo.com/path/to/project
  * [new tag]         test15 -> test15
  ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://remote.gitrepo.com/path/to/project'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

### Question

Why is `git push --tags origin master` trying to push something apart from the tag?
I am asking why the command is trying to push the branch to the remote and not why it is being rejected

Comment: See the docs, that's what they say it does: [*"...in addition to refspecs explicitly listed on the command line."*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---tags)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot push to GitHub - keeps saying need merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298291/cannot-push-to-github-keeps-saying-need-merge)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Comment: The problem has nothing with tags, it's a problem with non-fast-forward push of `master`. Run `git push origin master` and you will get the same error.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ahh, that does make a whole lot of sense. Thanks. My first command does push all tags and the second one pushes all tags and the ref specified... I've read through the push docs so often and never really read the whole sentence.

Comment: @phd I think this question is more specific on tags. I am asking why the command is trying to push the branch to the remote and not why it is being rejected, as this is obvious considering the initial situation. I would rather write a short answer myself if nobody else is doing it, what do you think about it?

Comment: I don't think the question *why `git push origin master` pushes branch `master`* needs an answer.

Comment: Well, I get it now. But it wasn't obvious for me in the first place. I thought the `--tags` flag would only push tags (to master) and no additional refs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am asking why the command is trying to push the branch to the remote and not why it is being rejected,

Because git push will push new commits and (with --tags) new tags.

- C is already pushed so nothing to push there
- the new tag is pushed.

In your second case, you are trying to reset the remote master branch (which is at D) to C (in addition of pushing tags).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.