# Unable to push after failed pulling in Git

Tags: git, github

I have [a repo that has only one file](https://github.com/georgeliu1998/tf_and_colab) (a Jupyter notebook file). Since the file was created using Google Colab, it didn't exist in my local repo, but was only on my GitHub repo.

I just added a README file and was trying to push from my local repo to GitHub. But since the remote repo was ahead of my local one, I wasn't able to push after committing.

I then decided to pull, but since I was not familiar with the syntax, I didn't specify any parameters after `git pull`. Then I tried again with `git pull origin master`, but now I got an error message saying there's a bug, and the repo name changed to "master|MERGING"...I know I probably need to pull the remote into a new local branch and merge it with my master branch, but I don't know how to do it here and also am scared to mess up the whole thing... Thanks for any tips!

```
georg@DESKTOP-9VE7F0E MINGW64 /d/Dropbox/WorkingDir/personal-projects/tf_and_col                                                                                                                                                                                               ab (master)
$ git commit -m "Add README file"
[master 13c0b76] Add README file
 1 file changed, 16 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 README.md

georg@DESKTOP-9VE7F0E MINGW64 /d/Dropbox/WorkingDir/personal-projects/tf_and_col                                                                                                                                                                                               ab (master)
$ git push origin master
To https://github.com/georgeliu1998/tf_and_colab.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/georgeliu1998/tf_and_cola                                                                                                                                                                                               b.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

georg@DESKTOP-9VE7F0E MINGW64 /d/Dropbox/WorkingDir/personal-projects/tf_and_col                                                                                                                                                                                               ab (master)
$ git checkout master
Already on 'master'

georg@DESKTOP-9VE7F0E MINGW64 /d/Dropbox/WorkingDir/personal-projects/tf_and_col                                                                                                                                                                                               ab (master)
$ git pull
remote: Enumerating objects: 20, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (20/20), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
remote: Total 18 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (18/18), done.
From https://github.com/georgeliu1998/tf_and_colab
   0a500ee..1238317  master     -> origin/master
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master


georg@DESKTOP-9VE7F0E MINGW64 /d/Dropbox/WorkingDir/personal-projects/tf_and_col                                                                                                                                                                                               ab (master)
$ git push origin master
To https://github.com/georgeliu1998/tf_and_colab.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/georgeliu1998/tf_and_cola                                                                                                                                                                                               b.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

georg@DESKTOP-9VE7F0E MINGW64 /d/Dropbox/WorkingDir/personal-projects/tf_and_col                                                                                                                                                                                               ab (master)
$ git remote
origin

georg@DESKTOP-9VE7F0E MINGW64 /d/Dropbox/WorkingDir/personal-projects/tf_and_col                                                                                                                                                                                               ab (master)
$ git pull origin
You asked to pull from the remote 'origin', but did not specify
a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote
for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.

georg@DESKTOP-9VE7F0E MINGW64 /d/Dropbox/WorkingDir/personal-projects/tf_and_col                                                                                                                                                                                               ab (master)
$ git pull origin master
From https://github.com/georgeliu1998/tf_and_colab
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... warning: failed to restrict f                                                                                                                                                                                               ile handles (2)

handle #0: 0000000000000434 (type 3, handle info (1) 0
handle #1: 0000000000000438 (type 3, handle info (1) 1

This is a bug; please report it at
https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/new

To suppress this warning, please set the environment variable

        SUPPRESS_HANDLE_INHERITANCE_WARNING=1

error: cannot spawn C:/Users/georg/AppData/Local/atom/bin/atom.cmd: No such file                                                                                                                                                                                                or directory
error: unable to start editor 'C:/Users/georg/AppData/Local/atom/bin/atom.cmd'
Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge.

georg@DESKTOP-9VE7F0E MINGW64 /d/Dropbox/WorkingDir/personal-projects/tf_and_col                                                                                                                                                                                               ab (master|MERGING)
$ git push origin master
To https://github.com/georgeliu1998/tf_and_colab.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/georgeliu1998/tf_and_colab.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

georg@DESKTOP-9VE7F0E MINGW64 /d/Dropbox/WorkingDir/personal-projects/tf_and_colab (master|MERGING)
$
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Any text your question depends on needs to be copied into the question as human- and machine-readable text, not screenshots.

Comment: Done. Can you confirm it's ok now? thanks@meagar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot push to GitHub - keeps saying need merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298291/cannot-push-to-github-keeps-saying-need-merge)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happened is that you have made changes locally to the branch when it was behind remote.  So when you committed locally, you created a new reference that was out of sync with the order of commits on the remote server.

```
origin/master: * -> * -> *
local/master:  \__ -> your commit
```

If it's just one commit you need, check out a new branch to save the current state

```
git checkout -b temp-updates
```

Then copy the commit hash from the first line of `git log`

> commit 166a17b4852f5b83a09c3198169d86959a68e3dd

Then switch back to `master` and reset it to be the same as your remote branch:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Now you can cherry-pick the commit with the changes you made:

```
git cherry-pick 166a17b4852f5b83a09c3198169d86959a68e3dd
```

Now you should be able to cleanly push

```
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

`git pull` equals `git fetch` plus `git merge`. When in doubt do not call `git pull`, instead call `git fetch` and then `git status` and stop to think what you want to do next.

In your case the subsequent `git merge` tried to merge the changes from `origin/master` with the changes in your local `master`, but it resulted in a conflict. `git` is expecting you to solve the conflict, and then `git add` the file to mark it as solved, and `git merge --continue` to complete the merge.

If you want to abort the merge you can do `git merge --abort` to go back to the normal status. If that command does not work, for whatever reason, a `git reset --hard HEAD` will clean your working directory. **WARNING**: `git reset --hard` will undo any non-commited change to your files!