# How to pull and push in a remote git repository

Tags: git

I worked in a project on my desktop and pushed it in master branch. Now i am working on my laptop with same project by downloading it in my laptop. After making some changes i want to marge this to my Github repository. But says an error which is

> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/mahfuz380/loginsystem' hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again. hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: "hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot push to GitHub - keeps saying need merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298291/cannot-push-to-github-keeps-saying-need-merge)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Answer (score 4):

Please follow the below steps when you try to push changes to remote branch.

1. First save your local changes using git stash command

   ```
   git stash
   ```
2. Pull the changes from remote branch

   ```
   git pull
   ```
3. Unstash your previously stash changes using below command

   ```
   git stash apply
   ```
4. Push your changes to remote branch

   ```
   git push origin
   ```

If you encountered any conflicts once you unstash the changes then please resolve the conflicts manually and then push.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

`git pull` first before you push. You might have to undo your changes first.

Answer (score 0):

As the message hinted, you should `pull` first to merge the changes, and push to remote.

```
git pull origin master
git push origin master
```