# How do I make my local changes show up to github repository?

Tags: git, github

I made a private github repository in which i cloned a repository I needed to work on. I have all their files locally and already finished coding but I am unable to reflect those changes onto my private github repository.

so this is what i did after cloning the repository

```
git checkout -b private
git remote add private git@github.com:<github-username>/<repositoryname>.git
git push private -u master
```

however this would always fail
when i tried again it worked but showed this

```
Enumerating objects: 42, done.
Counting objects: 100% (42/42), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (36/36), done.
Writing objects: 100% (42/42), 22.55 KiB | 7.51 MiB/s, done.
Total 42 (delta 15), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (15/15), done.
remote: 
remote: Create a pull request for 'master' on GitHub by visiting:
remote:      https://github.com/<githubusername>/<repositoryname>/pull/new/master
remote: 
To https://github.com/<githubusername>/<repositoryname>
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'private'.
```

it was supposed to say private -> master
so i know something is not right

What i am trying to do is have a new branch track my changes and have a remote for my private repository so i can push my new branch to the master branch of my repository but i think it is trying to push to the other person's master.

EDIT:
when i want to push it tells me to use this first

git push --set-upstream origin private

but when i do that i get denied access by the repository i cloned, this is why i think it is trying to push to their master instead of mine even tho i used my username and repository when setting it up

Comment: Note that you created a **remote** and a **branch** both named private. This will likely cause confusion. I suggest that you use different names for branches than for remotes.

Answer (score 0):

You created a branch named `private` (by running `git checkout -b private`), but then you've only pushed your `master` branch (by running `git push private master`). Remember that the syntax of the `push` command is:

```
git push <remote> <refspec>
```

That first parameter specifies the name of a remote, not the name of a branch.

If you want to push your local branch `private` to your remote named `private`, you would write:

```
git push -u private private
```

If you want to rename your local `private` branch to be `master` on the remote, you would write:

```
git push -u private private:master
```

Comment: when i do: git push  -u private private i get this error https://github.com/githubusername/repositoryname
 ! [rejected]        private -> private (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/vdorozco/roster'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

Comment: It looks like your local repository is not up-to-date with the branch of the same name on the remote. Only you know the proper response to this situation -- do you want to incorporate the remote changes? Or replace the remote `private` branch completely with your local branch?

Comment: my repository is just empty and i would like what i have locally to appear in my github repository

Comment: The error you are seeing suggests that the remote repository is *not* empty.  Adding `-f` (for `--force`) to your `git push` invocation will replace the remote `private` branch with your local `private` branch, although that wasn't what you were trying to do in your question (you were trying to push your local `private` branch to the remote `master` branch).

Comment: ah i see that is true, i pushed something on but it wasnt my local branch. i would like to replace that with my local branch.

Answer (score 0):

Everything I see in the question is Ok. There are no errors, local branch `master` has been successfully pushed to remote `master`. Your expectation to see `private -> master` is wrong: `private` is the name of the remote, `git` uses it to get its URL from config. But `git` pushes branches so it pushes `master` to `master` and you see `master -> master`.

If you have a branch named `private` you have to push it separately: `git push private -u private`. If you want the branch `private` to be pushed to remote `master`: `git push private -u private:master` but I recommend to make local and remote branch names to have exactly the same names.

As for the error

```
! [rejected] private -> private (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com/vdorozco/roster'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

see [Cannot push to GitHub - keeps saying need merge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10298291/7976758)

You need update your local repository with `git pull [--rebase] private master`.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+update+were+rejected

Comment: both of those push commands give the same error. and when i tried git pull [--rebase] private master, it said this fatal: ']' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: `[]` means an optional flag: a flag that is either used or not.

Comment: when i run git pull private master it says this:  * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
But my files arent on the github repository

Answer (score 0):

The given link you comment above doesn't work properly. As you told If you mind to push you local changes to remote simply you can do it from master.

```
git push origin master
```

Then if you get a rejected result and not allow to push your code first you have to pull the code from remote master. (This happen because your have remote changes so you have to get them and updated code first). So u should pull the code from master.

```
git pull origin master
```

Then you will show some process window over there. close it and push code again.

Case2:
If you are in a create a branch you can simply do it by:

```
git checkout -b <branch name>
```

Then you working over this branch commit over this branch. Then jump to master again by

```
git checkout master
```

If there any commits you want pull from remote master get them by

```
git pull origin master
```

Then your local master branch ahead new branch you have already made. So jump to that branch by checkout (like above jumb to master) & rebase with master

```
git rebase master
```

Then jump to master and again rebase with branch by

```
git rebase <branch name>
```

Then you can simply push your code to remote master

Comment: when i do git push origin master, i get denied by the user  i cloned my repository from. they are my collaborator in my private repository.

Comment: Do you fork it from another master repo or your repo is the mater repo?

Comment: it is from another master repo

Comment: Ok then, you talking about you fork it from another master and you have your master situation. In that case you should follow above git-rebasing without any conflicts. please go though the below tutorial you can understand it easily how does flow git-rebasing working.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1wnYdLEpgI

Answer (score -1):

`-u` is only required when you create a new branch. Otherwise, you should just do `git push private master` or as a shorthand `git push`.

Comment: when i do git push private, it says everything is up to date, however my files do not appear on the git hub repository website

Comment: @a-exelle What is the name of the current branch in your local repo? GitHub only shows the files on `master` by default. You can choose another branch from the the drop down on the left. Alternatively, you can change the default branch for your GitHub repo or push your changes directly to `master`.

Comment: its called private

Comment: @a-exelle By default, GitHub will first show the contents of a branch named `master`. You can choose to view a different branch from the drop down near the top of the page.