# Pulling changes from master to another branch

Tags: git, github

There is an open source project to which I want to contribute to. I forked it and set the `upstream` to my `master` from the remote `master`. Now I created another branch `add_func`. I made some changes to this branch but by the time I completed it, there were many changes in the remote one. I followed these steps:

1. `git pull upstream master && git push origin master`
2. Modify things in my local branch `add_func`
3. `git push orign add_func`

But I am getting error `Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes`.

**Note**: I already made a pull request with the `add_func` branch. By the time it got reviewed, there were changes. So, I cannot delete this branch or merge it into master.

PS: I know there are similar questions and I have checked them out but none of them have the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot push to GitHub - keeps saying need merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298291/cannot-push-to-github-keeps-saying-need-merge)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind+its+remote+counterpart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes

Seems like there are changes/commits in remote `add_func` that does not exit in local `add_func` branch. Pull `add_func` first, then push:

```
$ git pull origin add_func
$ git push origin add_func
```