# Failed to push to Bitbucket repository

Tags: git, bitbucket, push

I have a Bitbucket repository.I am the only one working on my remote repository. Everything works fine and suddently I cannot push anymore.
`git push origin master` returns

```
Enumerating objects: 145, done.
Counting objects: 100% (145/145), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (84/84), done.
fatal: unable to read 663ac546bf5ff0f76a5f41881b73b5c03c3d9bae
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly error:
failed to push some refs to ...
```

`git pull`  says **Already up to date**. Any idea/reason why getting this error suddently while I am the only one working on my repository?

Not sure if the issue is related to what happen before. What happens before is that my computer shutdown when I added some files `git add` in the index and I had not yet commited.

After getting my computer up, I had the following issue when runing `git ls-files -m`:

```
error: bad signature 0x00000000
fatal: index file corrupt
```

Seems my filesystem was corrupted and I fix the file system issue following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115854/how-to-resolve-error-bad-index-fatal-index-file-corrupt-when-using-git) (`rm .git/index` then `git reset`). I was able to run git commands and add my files to the index. After commit, I started having this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Even `git push origin master --force` does not work.
Have the same error 
`Enumerating objects: 145, done.
Counting objects: 100% (145/145), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (84/84), done.
fatal: unable to read 663ac546bf5ff0f76a5f41881b73b5c03c3d9bae
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to ...`

Comment: Have you pushed all local changes? Can you re-clone the entire repo without losing data?

Comment: No I cannot reclone without losing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All,

Finally the only way I was able to do was to reset the local repository and manually backup/copy my local changes. Then, clone a new repository from remote and manually add my backed up changes to the new cloned repository.

Thanks,