# adding a single file on another server to git repository

Tags: git

I created a script on a database server which I want to add to my remote repository.

I did the following in the directory which the SQL schema script exists

```
git init
git remote add origin https://my@bitbucket.org/me/myproject.git
git add schema.sql
git commit -m "added schema.sql"
```

when I do `git push` I get the following

```
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master
```

When I do `git push --set-upstream origin master` I get

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://my@bitbucket.org/me/myproject.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I want to add this single file to my remote repository. Is there a simple way of doing this with git?

Comment: Instead of doing your workflow, you should just clone the repo directly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot push to GitHub - keeps saying need merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298291/cannot-push-to-github-keeps-saying-need-merge)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `git init && git remote add ...` use:

```
git clone https://my@bitbucket.org/me/myproject.git
```

Then put your file where it belongs and:

```
git add schema.sql
git commit -m "added schema.sql"
git push
```

---

If you need to push this file to an established repo, then you'll need to pull:

```
git init
git remote add origin https://my@bitbucket.org/me/myproject.git
git pull
git add schema.sql
git commit -m "added schema.sql"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added remote repository, committed your changes, but you haven't pulled data from it. So first pull from the repository, then push to it.
    git pull
    git push