# How do I properly switch to a forked repository?

Tags: git, github

I am struggling to properly switch to my forked version of a repository. I was following the instructions [here](https://gist.github.com/jagregory/710671) for how to do so, but I seem to be running into a few errors.

I was able to run

```
git remote add my-fork git@github...my-fork.git
git fetch my-fork
```

But when I tried

```
git push my-fork
```

I got the error

```
To github.com:...my-fork.git
 ! [rejected]              master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:...my-fork.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I tried a number of online suggestions, including

```
git pull
```

```
git pull --rebase
```

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin master
```

These all gave the message "Already up to date."
How do I resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot push to GitHub - keeps saying need merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298291/cannot-push-to-github-keeps-saying-need-merge)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your fork does not have the same commits as the repository you are working on.

You can force your remote to match your local repository by using `git push -f`.

note that this can make you lose commits you have on your fork if they are not present on your local repository.

Comment: This does not work for me. I get the error `fatal: remote error: service not enabled: /git/<original-repo>.git`

Comment: @student1868 Can you double check your remote address?
Try calling `git remote -v`.

Comment: Okay, so when I tried `git push my-fork -f`, it worked, but I am having trouble properly switching to a branch on the fork. When I try to run `git checkout my-fork/master`, I get the a detached HEAD.

Comment: You get a detached HEAD since you are not creating a new local branch, but moving to a reference pointed by remote.

To move to your fork branch, you can use `git checkout my-fork/master; git checkout -b master`