# non-fast-forward error when trying to do a hard reset of my repository

Tags: git

I am trying to restore an earlier state of my repository. I want to remove all commits made since a certain point. There are twelve commits I want to remove. I tried running `git reset --hard HEAD~12` followed by `git push`, and I got the following error:

`! [rejected]        gh-pages -> gh-pages (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'the_repo'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

I read up about non-fast-forward and I think that I actually do want to do that (i.e. there is nothing in those twelve commits I want to save). How can I successfully undo those commits?

Comment: Use `git push --force`. This will overwrite the remote history with your local history, discarding any commits on the corresponding branch of the remote that don't exist locally.

Comment: Right, "non-fast-forward" is a jargon-y way of saying "this is going to lose some commits, perhaps forever". But you *want* that other Git repository to lose those commits, perhaps forever. So use `--force-with-lease` or `--force`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot push to GitHub - keeps saying need merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298291/cannot-push-to-github-keeps-saying-need-merge)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Answer (score 0):

I simply had to do `git push --force`

Comment: Help me understand how a `git push` resets the repo? That sounds like it forces the push to the remote, overwriting what's currently there in the remote.

Comment: `git push --force` fixes it after already doing the `git reset --hard HEAD~12` from the original question

Comment: That makes me think the `git reset --hard ...` command was the real fix. I didn't think a `git push --force` alone would do the trick. Thanks for the feedback.