# How to rebase pushed branches without ruining tree?

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm the only developer working in a repository, so there's no issue with ruining peoples' flow. However when I rebase locally and then try and push it to Bitbucket, it comes back telling me I need to pull the latest changes. I do that, and the rebase has completely ruined my clean tree.

Is there a way to push a rebase to the server without then having an additional "Merge branch" commit as part of it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rebase is fundamentally a "copy some commits, then discard the old commits in favor of the new and supposedly improved commits" operation.

Consider, for instance, this situation:

```
...--A--B--E--F   <-- master
         \
          C--D--G   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

You've finished your feature `feature`, but for whatever reason, you had to go create two commits on `master` while you were working.  So now `feature` could stand to be re-written.

No commit can *ever* change, so it's not actually possible to *replace* `C` with a new-and-improved variant, but we can make a new-and-improved `C'` to replace `C` anyway, using a temporary branch or Git's "detached HEAD" mode:

```
                C'  <-- HEAD
               /
...--A--B--E--F   <-- master
         \
          C--D--G   <-- feature
```

Commit `C'` does to commit `F` what commit `C` does to commit `B`.  The old (and now lousy) `C` has `B` as its parent, while the new improved `C'` has `F` as its parent.  So now we need to copy `D` to a new-and-improved `D'`, and then do the same again for `G`:

```
                C'--D'--G'  <-- HEAD
               /
...--A--B--E--F   <-- master
         \
          C--D--G   <-- feature
```

We're now ready for `git rebase`'s last trick.  It peels the name `feature` off of commit `G` and make `feature` point to `G'` instead:

```
                C'--D'--G'  <-- feature (HEAD)
               /
...--A--B--E--F   <-- master
         \
          C--D--G   [abandoned]
```

Since we can't even *see* the abandoned commits, in the local repository on your laptop, it looks as though history has always been this way: that you wrote commit `C'` based on `F`, and so on.  The hash IDs look random; no one but you will ever know about all this.

Only ... you did a `git push` of commits `C-D-G`, or at least some of them, to Bitbucket.  *They* have your old-and-lousy commits, pointed-to by *their* branch name `feature`.  You send them your shiny new ones—`git push origin feature`—and at the end of this, your Git asks them politely to move *their* `feature` name to point to commit `G'` instead of `G`.

This would, of course, cause *them* to abandon commit `G` in favor of the new and improved `G'`.  That's what you *want* them to do.  But they will say: *No, if I do that, I'll lose my precious commit `G`!*

All you have to do is tell them—or have your Git tell them—*yes, I know you could lose some commits, but do it anyway!*  That is, instead of a polite request, you have your Git send them a forceful command.

The way you do this is to add `--force` or `--force-with-lease` to your `git push` command.  That turns the polite request, *Please, if it's OK, set your `feature`* to a command: *Set your feature!*

The difference between `--force` and `--force-with-lease` is that the latter adds a safety check first.  Instead of just saying *Set your name `feature` to point to commit `G'`!*, your Git will say: *I think, based on my information, that your `feature` points to commit `G`.  If so, set it to point to `G'` instead.  If not, let me know that I goofed.*

The safety check is obviously usually good, but it's also unnecessary **if** you're the only one who ever puts new commits into the repository over on Bitbucket.

Comment: That's great, thanks @torek! So just to confirm, is there any downside to always just using `--force-with-lease`, even if I'm the solo developer? Seems it'd build a good habit, hehe.

Comment: It probably would, yes. I personally have some bad habits here (developed over 10+ years...) :-)