# How can i push the Master branch to another branch?

Tags: git

How can i push my Master branch to my old branch?

i am trying to use:

git push origin master:my_branch but i keep getting an error of

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> my_branch (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

i am still new in using Git. i am trying to use rebase, but i am having a hard time on understanding it. can anyone help me. any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: do you want to merge changes in your branch to master branch? or the master branch  changes to your branch?

Comment: i want to push master to my branch, so that the outdated branch will be updated already.

Comment: That's a very strange way to update a branch. The normal procedure would be to merge (or rebase) master into "your branch" locally, and then push your branch.

Comment: Edit: If you don't care about the contents of "your branch", then a force push, as suggested below, will work fine. But at that point you might as well just delete "your branch" and create a new one off of master

Comment: hi sir, i tried to use rebase, i really do have a hardtime to it. sorry sir.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot push to GitHub - keeps saying need merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298291/cannot-push-to-github-keeps-saying-need-merge)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The branch where you want to push to has commits that xou don't have locally.

If you want to have all commits, you can merge them by doing `git pull my_branch origin` first(and resolve possible conflicts).

If you want to overwrite the upstream branch, you can use `git push -f origin master:my_branch`

A force push will overwrite changes from other users. You can do a `git push --force-with-lease origin master:my_branch` if you only want to do it if no other user pushes to that branch during that time.

Comment: ```git push --force-with-lease origin master:my_branch``` by using this command, will my outdated branch will be updated just like the master?

Comment: A force push (`-f`) will completely overwrite the branch. But this may be a problem if other users have pushed to that branch if you don't know of this. `--force-with-lease` will fail in that case.

Comment: i am the only one who push with the outdated branch. i just want to make that old branch to be like the master branch.

Comment: Then use `git push -f origin master:my_branch`.

Comment: thank you sir. i did try the rebase, and i had really a hard time. sorry sir.