# Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes before pushing again

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

So I have an older version of my project in my github repository and I want to overwrite it with the new version of the project. The issue is that I was uploading the files right into github and not pushing anything so it's not synced up with my current project. I don't want to pull from github cause the code has changed. I'm using visual studio and I want to commit and push from visual studio is there anything I can do like forcing the current project to overwrite the one on master?

A simple solution to this is to create a new repository and use that, but I'm new and wish to learn if there's a solution to this.

Comment: Personally, I've installed the standard Git tools (https://git-scm.com/downloads) in parallel with MSVS (and MSVS Teams), so that I can easily run my own Git commands as needed.  In this case, you'd want `git pull --all`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot push to GitHub - keeps saying need merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298291/cannot-push-to-github-keeps-saying-need-merge)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind+its+remote+counterpart

Comment: I solved the issue, part of the solution was the other post you linked to where I had to use 'git push --force' however it wasn't working so while I was snooping around VS I saw a property to enable forcing with git then the command worked. Thanks all!